# How to repair kali linux 2 sana after removing dash?

Tags: kali-linux

I want it to remove the dash to dock since I installed another one but I accidentally removed dash. When I open terminal there is no **root@kali** it's just a **#** mark. Now I don't know how to repair it. The command that I entered is

```
apt-get remove dash
```

Comment: apt-get install dash

Comment: i did that but it says unable to locate package

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then restarted the computer and the problem was gone.

Comment: Here at Stack Exchange, we prefer quality, detailed answers. Can you expand upon this, if possible?

Comment: expand what?there is nothing else to expand i did a dist-upgrade and restarted the system and the dash was fixed.

Comment: Please see http://superuser.com/help/asking-rate-limited for information on why you must wait before asking another question.